# Is it possible to change the App display name to include unicode characters after starting cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, unicode

I tried changing the Text in the name tag iof config.xml to include a unicode character and when I tried to emulate iOS I received an error. Cleaned the project and then got an invalid argument error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use characters other than ASCII in `name` tag. So change Display Name of your app in XCode.

You need to search variable named `CFBundleDisplayName` in XCode and then write your Unicode-ish text.

Also check this answer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html